# Retrieve Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want to save push notification for my application on Android in following scenarios so that I can later display it in my apps message center.

1) Notification received when app is not running (neither in background nor foreground)

2) Notification is received by the device but is accidentally dismissed by the user.

I am aware that device maintains a a log of notifications (history). How can I fetch the notifications for my application from this log?

Answer (score 1):

If GCM is properly set up in the app, each time user's device receives a push notification, Android OS will trigger your implementation of GcmListenerService (see example https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/service/GcmService.java) and thus start your app.
If you want to store the received messages for the future reference, then do it in your implementation of `onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)`.

Comment: Thanks Roberto for your reply.
My application will launch only when user clicks on the notification received. But if she simply dismisses the notification, will onMessageReceive still be be called?

Comment: Yes, it will be called. Otherwise, I don't really understand how you show the notification itself.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Android OS isn't responsible for showing notifications. It just notifies your app that there is a push, and then you have a choice to show a notification  by using NotificationManager. Just locate the place where you show the notification, and it's going to be the place where you should store the notification data for the future reference.

Comment: One more clarification: by "will launch the app" I meant not launching the app's UI, but just spinning up the process of the app, initialising the Application instance, and calling onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) implementation.